# HashRouter and Google Analytics trouble tracking individual paths

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, google-analytics, react-router

I have already tried various solutions, I am currently using it, unfortunately GA only tracks one path ('/')

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import '../sass/main.scss';
import {
    HashRouter,
    Route,
    Switch,
} from 'react-router-dom';
const history = createHistory()
ReactGA.initialize('UA-XXXXXXX-1');
history.listen((location, action) => {
    ReactGA.pageview(location.pathname + location.search);
    console.log(location.pathname)
});

class Index extends Component {


    render() {

        return (
            <>
                <HashRouter history={history} >
                    <Route />
                    <ScrollUpButton ContainerClassName="AnyClassForContainer" />
                <Header />
                <Switch history={history}>
                    <Route exact path={"/"} component={() => <HomePage />}/>
                    <Route exact path={"/test"} component={() => <CategoryLinksNextPrev />}/>
                    <Route exact path={"/contact"} component={() => <Contact />}/>
                    <Route exact path={"/car/:category/"} component={CarCategory} />
                    <Route exact path={"/car/:category/:carname"} component={CarOnePageMain} />
                    <Route path="*" component={NotFound} />
                </Switch>
                <Footer />
                </HashRouter>
            </>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Index />, document.getElementById("index"));
```

In google analytics it only shows me one subpage, and exactly points to index.html

**UPDATE**

I found a very simple solution to this problem.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-ga

So that's my code now:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import '../sass/main.scss';
import {
    HashRouter,
    Route,
    Switch,
} from 'react-router-dom';
import Analytics from 'react-router-ga';

class Index extends Component {

    render() {

        return (
            <>
                <HashRouter >
                    <Analytics id="UA-xxxxxxx-1" debug>
                    <ScrollUpButton ContainerClassName="AnyClassForContainer" />
                <Header />
                <Switch history={history}>
                    <Route exact path={"/"} component={() => <HomePage />}/>
                    <Route exact path={"/test"} component={() => <CategoryLinksNextPrev />}/>
                    <Route exact path={"/contact"} component={() => <Contact />}/>
                    <Route exact path={"/car/:category/"} component={CarCategory} />
                    <Route exact path={"/car/:category/:carname"} component={CarOnePageMain} />
                    <Route path="*" component={NotFound} />
                </Switch>
                <Footer />
                </Analytics>
                </HashRouter>
            </>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Index />, document.getElementById("index"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue recently.

It looks like Google Analytics loads on the page load. If you click on a link, GA will run again as the new page is loaded from scratch with a new URL.

You have to manually fire the GA page views when user moves around your single page application.

More info here - https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/single-page-applications

Comment: could you give me an example of how to apply this to at least one subpage?
I am total green in the subject.

Comment: ```ga('set', 'page', '/new-page.html');
ga('send', 'pageview');```

Comment: `/new-page.html` is your new page URL